# Photoshop stuck at Align Selected Layers Based On Content

Tags: photoshop, astrophotography, image-stacking

I am trying to align a group of astro stacks (about 100 shots, masked) and Photoshop is stuck at:

[image]

The progress bar did move to this point in less than a minute, and has been stuck at this exact point about 30 minutes. Activity Monitor does show that Photoshop is using 100% CPU though.

Is it stuck, or is it just the progress bar that's not updating correctly and I should wait? This happened to me yesterday and it was stuck at that exact point too and I had to kill Photoshop and start over, now it's the same again.

I am on latest Photoshop 2015.5, MacBook Pro Retina mid-2014, 512GB internal SSD with ~300GB available, 480GB USB 3.0 external SSD ~300GB available and both are used as scratch disks, over 7GB of RAM allocated to Photoshop, so I don't think it's a resource issue. I've done astro stacks before and never encountered such problem.

Here is one of the about 100 stacked images:

[image]

UPDATE: It has been 4 hours and the progress bar is still stuck and Photoshop is still at 100%, interesting, as it must be doing *something*.

Comment: What do those images look like?

Comment: @null see my updated question

Comment: Is the pure black area part of the layer that should be aligned?

Comment: @null no of course not :) It's a part of the screenshot of the Photoshop's UI. the image is the one on the left with terrain masked and milkyway & stars visible.

Comment: Photoshop is not a great application to use for stacking astro-photo's. Try something like Deep Sky Stacker (free), Nebulosity ($), Maxim DL ($$$). You can then use photoshop to mask the area and presumably composite the final image.

Comment: @JamesScreech I know it's not the optimal. I've had some experience with DSS but I'm not happy with the results I get. it does align perfectly (I have no idea how it can align these 100 images with a transparency mask though) but I'm not happy with the resulting output image. I've saved it 32-bit float TIFF and tried to convert down to 8-16/bit in Photoshop but I just can't get it to convert correctly even though I'm experienced with 32-bit HDR conversion. I'll be looking at the other alternatives too, but any suggestions on how to handle the current situation within Photoshop?

Comment: 32-bit TIFFs from DSS can be a problem 16-bit usually better when taking the image into photoshop (I could never 32bit to work to my satisfaction in photoshop). DSS does not have anything like transparency masks, you will have to mask in photoshop to and add the foreground as another layer.

Comment: @JamesScreech the problem went away by itself on next try, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For some unknown reason, I've decided to give it a third try after killing Photoshop again, and after a few minutes, it started working:

[image]

It's the exact same file on the exact same computer. I only have one suspect: I have Parallels installed that runs Windows (with GPU acceleration enabled) inside a VM (the VM has nothing to do with Photoshop or my photography, but they obviously share resources, especially RAM and VRAM). In the first tries, I may have opened Parallels *while Photoshop was already running*. Maybe it created some sort of memory/VRAM problem. This time, when I launched Photoshop, Paralells was already running. Maybe Parallels trying to allocate some resources made Photoshop go crazy, but in the last one, it had already allocated what it needs to Photoshop went stable. This is my only possible explanation.

Comment: Having the exact same problem on 2018, but still cannot recover from it even after trying several times directly on macOS 10.13.